# Is it safe to assume a server would have PHP 5?

Tags: php

I've been learning up on PHP, and a lot of the time in the books and tutorials I read, features come up as having been introduced in PHP 5. I don't know anything about PHP history, so I don't know if I can safely use these features on most servers. I know in Python, adoption of new versions is very slow (few apps use 3.x, most desktops have 2.6, many server distros like Red Hat have versions as early as 2.4).

Is there a similar situation in the PHP ecosystem? My server has version 5.2, but are some servers still running PHP 4? What version of PHP can I safely assume a server would run?

Comment: At this time, few. [citation needed] - Some php5 functions, btw, can be emulated with PHP_Compat or upgradephp.

Comment: Any reasonably good host should support PHP 5, but the only "safe" way is to actually find out yourself.

Comment: @mario thanks for the tip, I'll look into that if I ever need to write PHP 4

Comment: My Web Hoster still offers PHP 3 as an option... But yes, any good Host should offer PHP 5, it's just that not all of them offer 5.2 (which means that features like json_encode/decode are missing) and some may even offer 5.3 which introduced a "namespace" Keyword that breaks old Versions of some popular software like MediaWiki

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP 5 was [released in 2004](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php), and PHP 4 reached End of Life at the [end of 2007](http://developers.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=07/07/14/0646216). You can safely assume that the server has at *least* 5.0.

PHP 5.3 was released in 2009, but there are still major pieces of software that have not fully taken into account everything that was changed in it; additionally, there are still distributions within their mainstream support cycles (like fairly recent versions of Ubuntu and Debian) that do not have it by default.

However, assuming PHP 5.2 is definitely safe.

Comment: It's hard to find a host *you would want to use* that offers less than 5.2.x. Almost all large hosts have it: Dreamhost, 1and1, Bluehost, etc.. Even free hosting like http://oatbox.net/ has it.

Answer (score 6):

At this point you should expect if not demand PHP 5.2.x. If your host doesnt have that, switch hosts - they dont deserve your money. PHP 5.3 on the other hand is a different story... not all shared hosts offer that yet so youll want to check it before deploying or setting up an account if thats the version youre targeting.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't assume minimum versions of any software installed anywhere. I'm sure there are people still running PHP4 in 2010. Having said that, I also wouldn't be developing any new software targeted at PHP4 in 2010. PHP 5.2 is probably a good, practical choice at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

[Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/) can be a useful resource for this type of question.  Here's an example: It appears that [RedHat](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat) went to PHP 5 in RHEL 5.5, which came out in March.  That's not actually so long ago; it wouldn't surprise me if some enterprise users haven't upgraded (I work at a large university and we have many production servers running RHEL 4).

Nonetheless, if we were going to run a PHP app on one of those servers, it's a safe bet that we would update PHP.  I'd use 5.2 and just document the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

So, we've got some current data after all:

http://phpadvent.org/2010/usage-statistics-by-ilia-alshanetsky

```
 PHP version    | usage at the end of 2010
 ---------------+----------------------------
 4.4            |  6%
 4.4            | 16%
 5.1            |  8%
 5.2            | 66%
 5.3            |  4%
```

---

And a more recent analyzation (says June 2011)

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5.3/all

```
 5.3            |  8.6%      (from 6.6%/0.764)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most web hosting providers are using PHP5. Some of them still provide both use of PHP 4 & 5 on a hosting account. In any case keep on with development in PHP5.