# When is Lithium php framework 1.0 expected to be released?

Tags: php, lithium

I am waiting for Lithium PHP framework's final release (1.0). Especially features like model joins and relationships.

Is there any publicly available info on when this release is expected?

Thanks!

Comment: Given that it depends on php 5.3 features, and that is only available on 4% of hosting services - it might take a while.

Comment: where is your source for this 4% of hosts?

Comment: Why don't you ask it's creators?

Comment: @RobertPitt: That was a statistic from december: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349655/is-it-safe-to-assume-a-server-would-have-php-5/4447984#4447984

Answer (score 1):

They have released database relationship (albeit basic, no HABTM as of yet) functionality on the x-relationships branch.

You can check out the source code [here](http://dev.lithify.me/lithium/source/branches/x-relationships).

There is also a blog post explaining it, check it out [here](http://www.harikt.com/content/relationship-support-lithium-aka-li3)

If this isn't complete enough for you, you can always check out another ORM such as doctrine and load it via `Libraries::add`.

Additionally if you have questions about releases you can always check out the `#li3` IRC channel on freenode, usually a couple of core developers floating around.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you ask them on their IRC channel: irc://irc.freenode.net/#li3

Answer (score 0):

You can download the public releases from the link below;

http://dev.lithify.me/lithium/versions